# Can I retrieve the return value of __exit__ from a python context manager?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I use context manager in python. In want to get some logs back from my `__exit__` method. So my code logs something like this:

```
class MyContextManager:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2)
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def __enter__(self)
        # Do some other stuff
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Do some tear down action, process some data that is 
        # created in __enter__ and log those results
        return my_results

with MyContextManager(value1=my_value1, value2=my_value2) as manager:
     # Do some stuff
```

So how could I access my_results which is returned from `__exit__` after (or at the end) of my with block. Is this even legit to return something other the True in the `__exit__` method?

Answer (score 8):

> Is this even legit to return something other the True in the `__exit__` method?

No, not really, but Python will just test for the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so you can get away with it. In other words, if you return a truthy object here, any exceptions will be suppressed. If there was no exception, returning a truthy value is just a no-op.

> how could I access my_results which is returned from `__exit__` after (or at the end) of my with block.

You can't. The `with` expression machinery consumed it.

You should make it available in some other way; set it as an attribute on the context manager object itself:

```
class MyContextManager:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2)
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def __enter__(self)
        # Do some other stuff
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Do some tear down action, process some data that is 
        # created in __enter__ and log those results
        self.my_results = my_results
        # returning None, we don't want to suppress exceptions
        return None

with MyContextManager(value1=my_value1, value2=my_value2) as manager:
     # Do some stuff

results = manager.my_results
```

The `manager` name is available after the `with` block has completed.

This is how the [`unittest.TestCase.assertRaises()` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) shares the captured exception, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helpful information! :) I didn't know that the instance of MyContextManager is still alive after the with block.